# linear interpolation using list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following list

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

l = [1,4,6,np.NaN,20,np.Nan,24]
```

I know I can replace the nan values using simple linear interpolation using `pandas` `interpolate` as follows

```
pd.Series([1,4,6,np.NaN,20,np.NaN,24]).interpolate()
Out[38]: 
0     1.0
1     4.0
2     6.0
3    13.0
4    20.0
5    22.0
6    24.0
dtype: float64
```

My question is: how can I get the same result by **only using list comprehensions**, standard numpy functions, but no built-in interpolation function (`pd.interpolate()` or numpy.interp()`)? That is, using directly the formula for linear interpolation between two points.

Comment: What makes `numpy.interp` not a "standard numpy function"?

Comment: the point is to use the basic formula for interpolation. Nothing already baked-in. I cannot get this to work with list comprehensions because you have to look at the entries "around" the nans... do you see what I mean?

Comment: Are you always going to have only one missing value between two available values?

Comment: yes. no extrapolation

Comment: Not extrapolation. I mean could you have `[1, nan, nan, 4]`?

Comment: This is more about the algorithm you would use to determine the interpolated value than it is about list comprehensions, which would just be the tool you use to implement the algorithm.

Comment: oh, sorry. Yes, you could have that. Then you just assume that the x-axis increases by one every time

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done in a single list comprehension, as you need to know values ahead to determine what`Nan` should be replaced with.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1,4,6,np.nan,20,np.nan,24]

res = [l[i] if not np.isnan(l[i]) else (l[i-1]+l[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(l))]
print(res)
```

Comment: Doesn't work if there is more than one consecutive `nan` value in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is really a fit for this question since it is not just a list comprehension, but I've figured out a solution that works for gaps with more than 1 consecutive `nan`:

```
import numpy as np

l = [1,4,6,np.nan,20,np.nan,24, 30, 31, np.nan, np.nan, 70, 75]

# 1 -> entry is nan
nans = np.isnan(l)

# 1 -> from number to nan, -1 -> from nan to number
diffs = np.diff(list(map(int, nans)))

# get "gap of nans" begin and end indices
gap_starts = np.where(diffs == 1)[0]
gap_ends = np.where(diffs == -1)[0]


for begin, end in zip(gap_starts, gap_ends):
    # number of nans in the gap
    nans_n = end - begin
    # difference of gap extrema
    nan_diff = abs(l[begin] - l[end+1])
    # step to add at each nan
    step = round(nan_diff / (nans_n + 1))
    # interpolate section from begin to end
    filling = [l[begin] + (step * n) for n in range(1, nans_n + 1)]
    # fix l with interpolated values
    l[begin+1:end+1] = filling
    
    
print(l)
```

produces

```
[1, 4, 6, 13, 20, 22, 24, 30, 31, 44, 57, 70, 75]
```